# secure websocket for https

Tags: security, websocket, ssl-certificate, wss

I have a local PHP server for my website and a local PHP server for websocket but websockets doesn't work anymore since I installed self-signed SSL certificats in WAMP. I have read that I have to use wss:// but when I change ws://localhost/xxx/server.php to wss://xxx/server.php but it doesn't solve my problem. I have accepted the certificat in firefox and chrome but it doesn't change anything. Any idea of what i supposed to do to repair websocket? Do I have to install certificat or key in my websocket PHP server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the same certificate for the web page, and access the page with `https://`, therefore the browser will prompt you to accept the self-signed certificate and the websocket will be able of connecting using `ws://`

Also, be sure you use different ports for `ws://` and `wss://`, some browsers get messed up if you start changing the connection of the same port.